# Protocol for device and language-specific questions

Tags: discussion, site-scope

I'm wondering how we should handle the issue of builder questions ([such as one of mine, for instance](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/14/what-are-the-best-security-practices-to-follow-when-building-an-iot-device)) where the answer might share some overlap with another SE focused on a device itself (e.g. Raspberry Pi, Arduino).

There will certainly be some questions related to scripting as well, which could fall under programing or network administration SE's. I'm just wondering, if we should consider marking the line.

Answer (score 6):

It's nearly inevitable that there will be *some* overlap between IoT and other Stack Exchange sites, especially ones related to embedded devices such as Raspberry Pis and Arduinos. The way that I distinguish between an IoT question and a device question is by asking "What is the question **actually** about?". Although this may seem a little bit vague, if a question is mainly about a device's uses in IoT, it's on topic. If it's simply a bug or question about a device, we should consider migration/closure, because it simply isn't about IoT itself.

[Your question](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/14/what-are-the-best-security-practices-to-follow-when-building-an-iot-device) is, in my opinion, firmly on-topic because the real subject of the question is about IoT, not a particular device.

Answer (score 6):

“There is another site where this question could be on-topic” is not a relevant consideration.

Is the question about IoT? Then it's on-topic. Is the question not about IoT? Then it's off-topic.

If a question is about using a Raspberry Pi for an IoT application, then it may well be on-topic both on Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange an here. But [please do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Comment: Does this not leave us in the slightly sticky spot of trying to define what an IoT application is?

Comment: @goobering Given that the topic of the site is IoT, we do have to define it to some extent.

Comment: Exactly. If it is on a Pi and about IoT it will still be on-topic on RPi.SE and here. The existance of this new branch of SE will not render the question off-topic on RPi.SE but I think we will reach a natural equilibrium as this site develops. The more subject matter experts this site attracts and expertise is available here the more likely migration and referral will get. (disclaimer: I am currently one of the community moderators on RPi.SE)